# NumPy: Understanding values in colour matrix

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I have an image which I have read and converted into a numpy array. I have then extracted each colour channel (R,G,B) of the image into three separate arrays:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('sample_images/fruit_half.png').convert('RGB')
image = np.array(image)

red = image[:,:,2]
green = image[:,:,1]
blue = image[:,:,0]
```

When I print the value of the "red" array, I get the following output:

```
 print(red)

 [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

I would like to know what do the numbers in the `red`, `green` and `blue` arrays represent. Do they represent the intensity of red/green/blue for a specific pixel? Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They stand for the pixel intensity of each color channel in the image. If you print out `image.shape` you will be able to access its properties

```
print(image.shape)
```

You will get something like this

```
(93, 296, 3)
```

This tells us the `(rows, columns, channels)` in the image. In this case, the image has three channels. If you print out each individual channel, they represent pixel intensity ranging from `0-255`. Every pixel is made up of the combination of these three channels. If instead you printed out the shape of the image and you got this

```
(93, 296, 1)
```

it means that the image only has one channel (a grayscale image). 
One thing to note is that OpenCV follows `BGR` convention while PIL follows `RGB`. Currently, you are splitting backwards. To split channels using PIL you can do this

```
image = Image.open('1.jpg').convert('RGB')
image = np.array(image)

red = image[:,:,0]
green = image[:,:,1]
blue = image[:,:,2]
```

Remember PIL uses `RGB` format where red is in channel 0, green in channel 1, and blue in channel 2.

To split channels using OpenCV you can do this

```
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
b,g,r = cv2.split(image)
```

or

```
b = image[:,:,0]
g = image[:,:,1]
r = image[:,:,2]
```

Taking this image as an example, you can use a histogram to visualize the channels.

[image]
[image]

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
b,g,r = cv2.split(image)

blue = cv2.calcHist([b], [0], None, [256], [0,256])
green = cv2.calcHist([g], [0], None, [256], [0,256])
red = cv2.calcHist([r], [0], None, [256], [0,256])

plt.plot(blue, color='b')
plt.plot(green, color ='g')
plt.plot(red, color ='r')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes they represent intensity, each value is an a 8-bit value from 0 to 255. If a value is 0 the red pixel is completely off and 255 is completely on. Usually people just use the image an array (well, opencv list them in the order blue green red). The image array holds a rgb value at every pixel (try printing image). This a standard for images and can be explained [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs101/image-1-introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

RGB picture is a digital matrix with 3 channel, each channel contain a value from 0 to 255 (if your dtype = uint8) to present the percentage of that color in that pixel. Look at the picture:

[image]

You can see that if we combine red and Green at 100% (mean 255), we have yellow, if we combine them in 100% together, we have white, etc. By this formula, each pixel will have x of Red and y of Green and z of Blue. 
Example:

[image]
Therefore, the value you see in red channel is the percent of red color in your picture.

Hope this useful!